# Why does casting AVG(intger_column) as DECIMAL return a minimum of six decimal places?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Consider this query:

```
WITH Scores (score)
     AS
     (
      SELECT CAST(score AS INTEGER)
        FROM (
              VALUES (0), 
                     (10), 
                     (10)
             ) AS Scores (score)
     )
SELECT AVG(CAST(score AS DECIMAL(19, 8))) AS precision_eight, 
       AVG(CAST(score AS DECIMAL(19, 7))) AS precision_seven, 
       AVG(CAST(score AS DECIMAL(19, 6))) AS precision_six, 
       AVG(CAST(score AS DECIMAL(19, 5))) AS precision_five, 
       AVG(CAST(score AS DECIMAL(19, 4))) AS precision_four
  FROM Scores;
```

Results:

```
precision_eight | precision_seven | precision_six | precision_five | precision_four 
     6.66666666 |       6.6666666 |      6.666666 |       6.666666 |       6.666666
```

Why do I always get a minimum of six decimal places? Is this documented behaviour?

(I'm running SQL Server 2008)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

AVG of decimal always returns a "decimal(38, s) divided by decimal(10, 0)" data type ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177677.aspx))

You have to cast the AVG result to the desired precision.

Answer (score 2):

I was about to post something similar to [Jappie's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3943265/why-does-casting-avgintger-column-as-decimal-return-a-minimum-of-six-decimal-pl/3943331#3943331) along with this example to illustrate what's happening behind the scenes.

```
declare @a int
set @a = 0
declare @b int
set @b = 10
declare @c int
set @c = 10

declare @n decimal(10,0)
set @n = 3

select cast((@a+@b+@c) as decimal(38,4))/@n
```